# Xcode(Swift)で、UIButtonを条件によって表示する方法

Tags: swift, xcode

Storyboardに設置したUIButtonを3回押したら、全く新しいUIButtonが表示されるというものなのですが、
その全く新しいUIButtonの表示の仕方が分かりません。
(最初から表示されているUIButtonではないので、その表示の仕方が分からないです)

```js
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //変数を作成
    var tapCount = 0
    var targetCount = 3

    //ボタンを紐付けする
    @IBAction func PushButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        tapCount++
        if (tapCount == targetCount){
          //ここのボタン表示のコードが分からない
          }
    }
}
```

お詳しい方がいましたら、ご回答どうか宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102191/make-a-uibutton-programatically-in-swift に同様の質問がありましたが、煩雑になるので出来るだけデザイナーを使用してhiddenを切り替えるなどしたほうが良いかと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pgrhoさんの貼ってくださっているリンク先に記載がありますが、
ボタンに限らず、サブビューを追加する場合は下記が基本になります。
・追加したいビューを生成する
・ビューの位置と大きさを設定する
・親ビューに追加する

```
// サンプル
func addSubView() {
    // ビューの生成
    let subView = UIView()
    // 位置と大きさを設定
    subView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 500)
    // 親ビューに追加
    self.view.addSubview(subView)
}
```

ただ、せっかくStoryboardを使用しているのであれば、
pgrhoさんが記載してくださっているように、Storyboard上に対象のボタンを設置して
hiddenを使用して表示・非表示を切り替えた方がシンプルで分かりやすいと思います。

Comment: @IBAction func PushButton(sender: AnyObject)で紐付けをすると、
「.hidden」が使えません。それともご回答頂いたようにfuncで関数を設定するのが正しいのでしょうか。

Comment: AnyObjectは特定の型ではないのでキャストが必要です。ただ、今回の場合は「全く新しいUIButtonを表示したい」ということですので、senderに対して属性変更を行っても意味がありません。IBOutlet, IBAction等含め、 Storyboardの基本的な使い方をお調べになると良いかと思います。その際ですが、この辺りの考え方はObjective-Cでも変わらないと思いますので、検索範囲をObjective-Cまで広げてみると良いかもしれません。

Comment: IBActionではなく、IBOutletで解決致しました！なるほど……Swiftのサイトだけを見ていましたが、次回からはObjective-Cでも検索してみますね！有り難うございました。